# UseGeneratedKeys not working for parameterType="map"

Tags: java, mybatis

Using MyBatis 3.2.7

**Scenario 1:**

POJO:

```
public class Project {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { ... }
    public void setId(...) { ... }
}
```

DAO:

```
public void update(@Param("parentId") long parentId, @Param("project") Project project);
```

DAO.xml

```
<update id="updateProject" parameterType="map" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="project.id" keyColumn="project_id">
```

Given these classes/files, I expect that if I call  the `update`-method of the DAO with a `Project` that has no id set yet, that after it has been merged/inserted into the database, `project.id` contains the generated id, but apparently it's still null.

**Scenario 2:**

In the same DAO, I have another setup that works perfectly fine:

POJO:

```
public class Plan {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { ... }
    public void setId(...) { ... }
}
```

DAO:

```
public void update(@Param("plan") Plan plan);
```

DAO.xml

```
<update id="updatePlan" parameterType="Plan" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="plan_id">
```

**Question**

Due to that in scenario 2 it works perfectly fine and it doesn't work in scenario 1, I assume that the use of generated keys isn't supported when using a map as `parameterType`. Is this true?

Comment: http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Problem-with-setting-a-key-on-an-Insert-on-method-w-multiple-params-td3513325.html Looks like it really isn't supported if multiple parameters are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
<update id="updateProject" parameterType="map">
    <selectKey keyProperty="project.id" resultType="Long" order="BEFORE">
        select nvl(#{project.id}, project_id_seq.nextval) from dual
    </selectKey>
    ...
</update>
```